# LINQ JOIN Straight to Object

Tags: c#, linq

I am rather new to LINQ and I have implemented a LINQ statement that does a join and then I get the results of the query, iterate through the results and assign each result to a new object and then add the object to a list of objects. Is there a more elegant way to do the following such that I am selecting right into the object list?

Thanks and much appreciated

```
        var clubAttendeeEducationList = new List<ClubAttendeeEducation>();



        var r = (from oer in db.OnlineEducationRegistrations
                join oec in db.OnlineEducationCourses on oer.OnlineEducationCourseId equals
                    oec.OnlineEducationCourseId
                where
                    (oer.MasterCustomerId.Equals(userId) && oer.DateCompleted >= start.Date &&
                     oer.DateCompleted <= upUntil.Date && oer.DateCompleted != null)

                select new {OnlineEducationRegistration = oer, oec.CourseTitle}).ToList();

        foreach (var item in r)
        {

            var educationItem = new ClubAttendeeEducation
                    {
                        Session = item.CourseTitle,
                        Date = item.OnlineEducationRegistration.DateCompleted.Value

                    };

            clubAttendeeEducationList.Add(educationItem);
        }


    return clubAttendeeEducationList;
```

Comment: Well why are you using `select new { ... }` instead of just `select new ClubAttendeeEducation { Session = oec.CourseTitle, Date = oer.DateCompleted.Value }`? It's not clear why you've chosen this approach...

Comment: @JonSkeet My thinking was that I don't need all of the columns from the joined table so that's why I did it like:  select new {OnlineEducationRegistration = oer, oec.CourseTitle}).ToList(); Like I said, I am kinda new to LINQ so that's why I am looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you are creating new anonymous object in your query you can create object of any type you want, and turn result into list.

```
var clubAttendeeEducationList = (from oer in db.OnlineEducationRegistrations
                                /* rest of the query */
                                select new ClubAttendeeEducation
                                {
                                    Session = item.CourseTitle,
                                    Date = item.OnlineEducationRegistration.DateCompleted.Value
                                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't select out an anonymous object if you actually want objects of another type.  Simply select out the type that you *actually* want directly in your original query.